# Regular Expression Substring in SQL on two character delimeter

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring, whitespace

I am attempting to take a delimited string and return each substring between delimiters. This is used in a bigger function I am writing thus the delimiter is usually a variable.

A very common delimiter that we use is ', ' and thus that has been my number one test case. I have different problems depending on how I format the delimiter in the regular expression.

The following are the different things I have tried and the results:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(, )' || ']+', 1, LEVEL) item
        from dual
        connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(, )' || ']+', 1, LEVEL

select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(,\s)' || ']+', 1, LEVEL) item
        from dual
        connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(,\s)' || ']+', 1, LEVEL

select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(,[:blank:])' || ']+', 1, LEVEL) item
        from dual
        connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR ('foo bar', '[^' || '(,[:blank:])' || ']+', 1, LEVEL
```

The first and third attempt separates 'foo' and 'bar' on the space even though there is no comma. The latter attempt works as hoped keeping 'foo' and 'bar' on the same line, but if the string has an s in it (e.g. horse) the result is 'hor' 'e'.

My understanding of regular expressions and regexp_substr tells me that

```
'[^(,\s)]+'
```

should separate the strings whenever it comes across a comma and then whitespace. But clearly this is not happening. I have yet to find anyone with a similar issue as me. Any help would be much appreciated

For reference I am working in SQL Developer on an Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I don't understand your question very well, why don't you use `[^,[:blank:]]+` instead?

Comment: @Aramillo - that would split on comma *or* space, not the two as an adjacent pair of characters. The OP's use of parentheses to treat them as a unit doesn't work inside the matching character list though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Ahh, now i get it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused about how the matching character list works. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIEGEI):

> [char...] Matching Character List
>
> Matches any single character in the list within the brackets. In the list, all > operators except these are treated as literals:
>
> Range operator: -
>   POSIX character class: [: :]
>   POSIX collation element: [. .]
>   POSIX character equivalence class: [= =]

So in your pattern `'[^(,\s)]+'` each of those characters are treated as literals; the `\` is not making the `s` be treated as a whitespace character, it's just an `s`, so it is matched in `horse`. And the parentheses are also literals, so they are not enclosing the pair of characters in your delimiter, each just matches an actual parenthesis in your string. In your first and third attempt you get a match on just a space because each character in the match list is independent, they aren't combined by the parentheses as you're expecting.

As far as I'm aware you can't negate a pair of values (though regex isn't a strong point so there's a good chance I'm wrong about that). One option is to replace all appearances of your delimiter with a character you know won't be present - depending on your actual data, you might have to pick an unprintable character or an obscure Unicode character - and then use that in the regex.

For example, using bind variables for brevity and a hash as a character I know isn't present:

```
variable string varchar2(20);
variable delimiter varchar2(2);

exec :string := 'foo bar, the cad, left';
exec :delimiter := ', ';

select regexp_substr(replace(:string, :delimiter, '#'),
  '[^#]+', 1, level) as item
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(replace(:string, :delimiter, '#'),
  '[^#]+', 1, level) is not null;

ITEM                
--------------------
foo bar              
the cad              
left
```

Comment: Thank you for schooling me on the matching character list. I was just thinking of how in a normal regular expression, '(abc)*' would match abcabc and not aaa. Oracle SQL's regex's seem to be a little wonky in use but thats neither here nor there. And your suggestion works perfectly, I don't believe we will ever have hashes in fields that this function would be used on, and I can just include that in the documentation and if it is a problem, take your advice and go for a non printable character. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You also can do this:

```
select trim(regexp_substr('foo bar, the cad, left','[^,]+',1,level)) from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('foo bar, the cad, left',',')+1;
```

This query search for a `,` not `,(space)`. But i think you will get the same result. This don't work if you have `foo,bar, the cad, left` and expect 
`foo,bar`,`the cad`,`left`

Comment: That matches just a comma, as well as a comma followed by a space. That might work for the OP here though. (Depends what the less common delimiters are I suppose).

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole i was editing while you comment.:)

Comment: Trim is an interesting way to go about it, thank you for that, I only chose the other option because it seemed that it would be more all purpose

Comment: Yes, you did it right, i think @AlexPoole answer is more generic.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a text pattern which utilizes a non-greedy quantifier**

March through a string looking for multiple occurances of the pattern, `'(.+?)(, |$)'`:

- The pattern,`(.+?)`, is a character group. The `.` refers to any/all characters and the `+?` is a non-greedy quantifier for 1 or more characters.
- The pattern, `(, |$)`, looks for an occurrance of the `', '` or (alternation operator, `|`) the end of string, `$`. This is the 2nd character group.

Finally, use a sub-expression to reference only the 1st character group

```
SCOTT@dev> VAR tval VARCHAR2(500);
SCOTT@dev> EXECUTE :tval := 'foo,bar, great';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@dev> SELECT regexp_substr(:tval,'(.+?)(, |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) t_val
  2  FROM dual
  3    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:tval,'(.+?)(, |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
  4  /

T_VAL
--------
foo,bar
great

SCOTT@dev> VAR tval VARCHAR2(500);
SCOTT@dev> EXECUTE :tval := 'foo, bar, great';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@dev> /

T_VAL
--------
foo
bar
great

SCOTT@dev> VAR tval VARCHAR2(500);
SCOTT@dev> EXECUTE :tval := 'foo,bar,great';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@dev> /

T_VAL
--------
foo,bar,great

SCOTT@dev> VAR tval VARCHAR2(500);
SCOTT@dev> EXECUTE :tval := ',foo, bar, great';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@dev> /

T_VAL
--------
,foo
bar
great
```